# How to stop matcher on the first occurrence of a char?

Tags: java, regex

I would like to using Matcher in this string:
 **#Function()(a)**

To select just: **#Function()**

I'm using this regular expression:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\#.*\\)");
Matcher match = pat.matcher(s);
```

And I'm selecting more than I want : **#Function()(a)**.

How can I stop Matcher in the first occurrence of **')'**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `.*` is greedy, so it will match as much as it possibly can while keeping the whole thing legal.  You can make it reluctant by using `.*?` instead, then it will match as little as possible while keeping the whole thing legal.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `.*` use `[^\\)]*`

try this:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\#[^\\)]+\\)");
```